# Destroy [wworld-building]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

This tag seems to be created by an error. I've fixed the only question that use this [wworld-building](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wworld-building) with [world-building](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building)

Let's destroy this tag.

Comment: Whoops! I went to type in the [weather] tag and didn't realize I'd somehow stuck a "w" somewhere else in the tags as well! But yeah, as BESW's answer says, orphaned tags are automatically incinerated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've already done it!

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
>   ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/244929))

By removing the tag from all questions, you've lined it up for unceremonious burnination. Congratulations!

Comment: @Vylix "burnination" gets used colloquially (around here) to refer either to the automated-type destruction of a tag that will happen here and to a process that mods can use to manually remove a tag from all questions it's on and destroy it. (Over on SO it's a [clearly-defined process involving hordes of users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/7317818).) (In [chat] it's just a [routine occurrence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=burninate&user=&room=11).)